# Gradle how to show build failed message

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

How to creat a task to show build failed message in the end?

I have tried

```
task.setEnabled(false)
```

but it shows BUILD SUCCESSFUL. I tried also

```
ant.fail('message')
```

It worked and stoped the tasks. But is there any function to show BUILD FAILED message instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: Don't understand the question. A disabled task will never fail.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser so how could we fail a build? Just show build failed message.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve and why, and how it relates to disabling a task.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser It may be better now. I don't speak very well english.

Answer (score 3):

The way to programmatically fail a build is `throw new GradleException("helpful message")`.